# New Lines inside DB dont get displayed in textarea

Tags: php, mysql

Some strange behaviour with the same script on different Websites here. Here you go:

I have an textarea where users enter text. They also do newlines using enter. That is stored inside the mysql db like this:

Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n\r\nLine Three

The problem occures when displaying that text inside a textarea again.
In most cases everything works fine. The following is displayed inside the textarea:

```
Line One
Line Two

Line Three
```

On some websites however only the following is displayed inside the textarea:

```
Line One
Line Two    
Line Three
```

Inside the db the two newlines (\r\n\r\n) are still there. Only one is displayed however.

This happens like i said only on some websites, in most cases multiple newlines like this \r\n\r\n are displayed fine.

**UPDATE:**
Seams like JSON has something to do with it. It is an JSON string containing a string like "Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n\r\nLine Three".

```
{"mystring":"Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n\r\nLine Three"}

$row = $db->load(); // get the json string
var_dump($row); // \r\n\r\n still inside!
$jrow = json_decode($row);
var_dump($jrow->mystring); // on some servers multiple newlines are chopped to one
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the double `\r\n` is actually going into and coming back out of the database correctly? without any code your question is basically impossible to answer. it could be a bug on insertion, it could be a bug on retrieval, it could be a bug on building the html page, it could be a bug on data entry, blah blah blah

Comment: the double \r\n is going into the db. and its comming out. like i said on most sites the double \r\n is displayed fine like two newlines. only some sites cut that down to one.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [n2lbr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when displaying the DB value in the textarea. Does that help at all? It's worked for me in the past.

Comment: `<br>` tags won't create newlines in `textarea` elements.

Comment: yep. i don't want <br> tags inside the textarea but actual linebreaks.